# H2O Performance metric : AUCPR not available?

Tags: python, machine-learning, h2o

I'm dealing with a binary classification problem and I tried using the performance metric AUCPR in H2O since I have an imbalanced dataset.

However, I get the following error when I try calling the aucpr metric.

```
# entrainement
aml_sans_class_balance.train(x=x_h2o, y=y_h2o, training_frame=train_h2o, validation_frame=valid_h2o)


# Score auc
prediction = aml_sans_class_balance.leader.model_performance(test_data=test_h2o)
tot_auc_score_sans_class_balance.append(prediction.aucpr())
print('score auc à itération', j+1,':',prediction.aucpr())

----------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError: type object 'H2OBinomialModelMetrics' has no attribute 'aucpr'
```

Thank you for your help.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to call `prediction.pr_auc()` method instead of `prediction.aucpr()` method.

See the doc: 
http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/metrics.html#h2o.model.metrics_base.MetricsBase.pr_auc